# TFS 2013 Git template - get the sources dir

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have the TFS 2013 build controller with Git,

I am trying to customise the GitTemplate.xaml to get a command line script to run after the build.

For this I need the sources dir (e.g. where the build controller clones the git repo).

I tried getting it like so:

```
<mtbac:GetEnvironmentVariable x:TypeArguments="x:String" sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="GetEnvironmentVariable`1_1" Name="[WellKnownEnvironmentVariables.BinariesDirectory]" Result="[sourceDir]" />
```

but the value is always null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this you need to use the `GetBuildDirectory` activity ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.workflow.activities.getbuilddirectory.aspx))

Then append the SourcesFolder value from `InitializeEnvironment` activity.

Answer (score 0):

The GitTemplate is able to run scripts out of the box and does not require customization for this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn376353.aspx

[image: GitTemplate.12.xaml]

There are various places that you can inject the script. While the build is executing there are environmental veriables available for most of what you want.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850448.aspx

Try not to customize your .xaml build templates...

Comment: Use GitTemplate.12.xaml